How do I pin a channel in the dope sheet
When I try to animate, It gets annoying when I have to constantly switch back between bones just to see the channels. Ive heard of "pinning" channels but I do not see anything to pin it.
I want to make the channels stay there so I can edit other bones while seeing the other channels.


Make these show at the same time

There are two ways to achieve this:
one is to select a bone, pin it on the dopesheet window, then select the other.

Another way is to open two different dopesheet windows, one limited filtering by name, the other limited filtering by selection (as default).


Disable the Only Show Selected option:


A bit of a workaround but also works (I'm using Blender 4.1):
Select the opjects you want to pin then switch from the Dope Sheet window to the Graph Editor with Ctrl-Tab and pin them there. Then Ctrl-Tab back to the Dope Sheet. There are also more options to pin there like pinning everything for an object. (including for instance ChildOf object constraints)
Small gotcha: you need to go back to the Graph editor to un-pin them ;)


